# Unity code with rare null reference that I can't figure out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, null, nullreferenceexception

I have a simple function in my Unity game code where I am looking for a "work spot" - an empty place for my NPCs to do some task.

This code works perfectly well 99.999% of the time, but throws a NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION very occasionally and I can't for the life of me figure out where. I have tried to catch every possible place where something could be unassigned and can't find it. There must be some edge case I am missing, or something in my code that misbehaves under some strange circumstances.

So my code is flawed and I don't understand where. Help me improve it:

```
    public Transform[] workSpots;


    public Transform findAvailableWorkSpot() {
        if (workSpots == null || workSpots.Length == 0) return null; // sometimes we have no work spots
        int i=0;
        while (i<10) {
            Transform spot = workSpots[Random.Range(0, workSpots.Length)];
            if (spot != null && spot.childCount == 0) {
                return spot;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // couldn't find one randomly, let's just iterate over them:
        foreach (Transform spot in workSpots) {
            if (spot != null && spot.childCount == 0) {
                return spot;
            }
        }

        Debug.LogError("could not find free workspot on "+gameObject.name);
        return null;
    }
```

Logic:

- first, try up to 10 times to get a free random work spot. I parent the NPC to the work spot when he is working there, so `spot.childCount == 0` is true if the spot has no NPC on it right now.
- if that fails, then I just iterate over all of them and pick the first free one.
- it is ok to return null here, the calling code will handle that

The Diagnostic backend tells me that 2-4 times a day someone experiences a Null Reference Exception in this function, but diagnostics doesn't tell me the line number and I've never seen it locally. I'm looking at it again and again and I can't spot where it could be. Maybe something more fundamental is wrong with my code?

---

Additional Information:

- workspots is initialized in Awake() and is never again changed, so I am sure that the test at the beginning of the function works and it's not possible that it goes to null while the function is running.

Comment: How do you initialize `Transform[] workSpots;`? take into account the last index is the length - 1. Maybe you are out of range when int `workSpots[Random.Range(0, workSpots.Length)]` equals `workSpots.Length`?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay a `NullReferenceException` != `IndexOutOfRangeException` ;) Also note that for **int** parameters the upper bound of `Random.Range` is **exclusive**! So `Random.Range(0, workSpots.Length)` will never return `workSpots.Length`

Comment: Is another thread setting `workSpots` to null while that method is executing? Presumably something's setting it to null at some point, or you wouldn't need that initial null-check. You can avoid that by creating a local copy at the start of that method

Comment: Could you post more context. Like for starters what exactly does your exception message and stacktrace say? It should tell you already the exact code line were the exception is thrown => set a break point there and check for what conditions in what circumstances this happens => then figure out why

Comment: @derHugo That's only true if symbols were available when the crash happened. I don't know how Unity works here, but that might not be possible or practical

Comment: @canton7 also note that going multi-threaded is quite unlikely in this case (in general  most of the Unity API is not thread-save and can only be used on the Unity main thread anyway). So this is quite a far shot ;)

Comment: @canton7 but yeah true sounds like Diagnostics actually doesn't tell you that info

Comment: Oh, what is `gameObject` and can it ever be null?

Comment: What if this is called on an alredy destroyed object and `gameObject` is null?

Comment: @canton7 yeah same thought on second look ;) [`Component.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) can be "equivalent to" `null` in the rare case that this method is called in a frame where this object was destroyed .. but in this case the call to `findAvailableWorkSpot` itself should already throw ... except if it comes from the same class and not from the outside. Not sure though .. I think this case would rather throw `MissingReferenceException` which is a custom one from Unity

Comment: @derHugo - unfortunately, the Unity Diagnostics doesn't give you line numbers. This is a very rare exception and I've never seen it when running the game in the editor.

Comment: @derHugo this method is called from outside this class, that's why it's public.

Comment: Have you tried executing with the editor in debug mode? In rare cases (but especially when tight loops and arrays\lists are invovled) that provides clearer information. EDIT: Since you mention Unity Diagnostics, I guess you never had this occur in the editor? I fear the deployed code is tightly optimized and thus omits the correct error line number. Had that happen in the editor outside of debug mode.

Comment: @AlexGeorg correct. I've never had this happen in the editor, and most players never experience it, either.

Comment: You can get the exact line number with IL2CPP using Sentry: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/unity/configuration/il2cpp/

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly an answer to where exactly the exception comes from.

But if you are open to using Linq you can simplyfy your code a lot!

I would simply use

```
using System.Linq;

...

public Transform[] workSpots;

public bool TryFindAvailableWorkSpot(out Transform freeSpot)
{
    // First heck this component even is alive
    if (!this || workSpots == null || workSpots.Length == 0)
    {
        freeSpot = null;
        return false;
    }

    // First "Where" filters out only those spots that exist and have no children
    // then "OrderBy" randomizes these results
    // then we take the first one or null if there isn't any
    freeSpot = workSpots.Where(spot => spot && spot.childCount == 0).OrderBy(spot => Random.value).FirstOrDefault();

    // use the implicit bool operator for checking if we have found a valid reference
    return freeSpot;
}
```

and then instead of using

```
var spot = yourClass.findAvailableWorkSpot();
```

and having to again check for `null` and potential exceptions you would rather simply do the check in the same line using e.g.

```
if(yourClass.TryFindAvailableWorkSpot(out var spot))
{
    ... Do someting with spot
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("could not find free workspot");
}
```

See

- [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)
- [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)
- [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html)
- [Linq `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)
- [`Unityengine.Object` implicit `bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)

Comment: It might not answer the question directly, but sometimes simply refactoring the code and making it leaner makes obscure errors go away, so I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you are looking at the right place where the exception happened. The way you've written the code it's just **not possible** for `workSpots` to be null or empty.

The only places where I can see a null reference exception happening is if you are trying to access `workSpots[index]` -> and that returns a Transform object that is null and you try using it (but in your code you are prepared for that).
Maybe the places where you use that particular method do not check if the Transform that you are returning is null before trying to access it.
If your code is well written and you don't believe it then the null reference exception is probably caused by `gameObject.name` when trying to log an error. If it isn't that then I have no idea honestly.

Comment: The exception definitely happens in this function, at least according to Unity Diagnostics. I also look at the code again and again and can't figure out where it could possibly be, that's why I'm asking the community.